# Listener method not called when using Spring JMS

Tags: spring, spring-jms

I have an application built on Spring 4.1. I am trying to create a JMS Listener using XML configuration and trying to convert the incoming XML message to Java Object. Below is my xml configuration:

```
<jms:listener-container concurrency="10"
    connection-factory="connectionFactory"
    message-converter="marshallingMessageConverter">
    <jms:listener destination="destination.name" ref="messageListener" method="processMessage"/>
</jms:listener-container>

<bean id="messageListener" class="com.example.CustomMessageListener">
</bean>

<bean id="marshallingMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MarshallingMessageConverter">
        <property name="marshaller" ref="xmlMarshaller"/>
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="xmlMarshaller"/>
</bean>

<bean id="xmlMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound" value="com.example.CustomObject"/>
</bean>
```

The Class `com.example.CustomMessageListener` looks like below:

```
public class CustomMessageListener{
    public void processMessage(Message message, CustomObject object){
        //Do Something.
    }
```

Now when I post a message into the destination queue, the method `processMessage()` on the Listener is not getting called and I am getting the below error in spring logs:

```
Failed to invoke target method 'processMessage' with arguments {com.example.CustomObject@52ee271d}; 
nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
com.example.CustomMessageListener.processMessage(com.example.CustomObject).
```

Now if I change the Listerner method's argument to just accept the CustomObject, it works and I get the CustomObject properly constructed from the XML:

```
public void processMessage(CustomObject, object)
```

But I also need the original `javax.jms.Message` instance and according to [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-annotated-method-signature) documentation, it should be possible to receive that instance by specifying it in the parameter list.

Can somebody please help me out here?

Comment: Yes it is possible but if you look at the documentation that is for the Annotated version of the listener NOT the XML defined version of the listener.

Answer (score 0):

try this it should work

```
<jms:listener-container concurrency="10"   connection-factory="connectionFactory" >
    <jms:listener destination="destination.name" ref="defaultMessageListener"  />
</jms:listener-container>

<bean id="messageListener" class="com.example.CustomMessageListener">
</bean>

<bean id="marshallingMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MarshallingMessageConverter">
        <property name="marshaller" ref="xmlMarshaller"/>
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="xmlMarshaller"/>
</bean>

<bean id="xmlMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound" value="com.example.CustomObject"/>
</bean>

<bean id="payloadArgumentResolver" class="org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.PayloadArgumentResolver">
    <property name="converter" ref="marshallingMessageConverter"/>
</bean>

<bean id="handlerMethod" class="org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod">
    <constructor-arg
        ref="messageListener" index="0"/>
    <constructor-arg
        value="processMessage" index="1"/>
    <constructor-arg
        value="javax.jms.Message"  type="java.lang.Class" index="2"/>
    <constructor-arg
        value="com.example.CustomObject"  type="java.lang.Class" index="3"/>
    <property name="argumentResolvers" ref="payloadArgumentResolver"   />
</bean>

<bean id="defaultMessageListener" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter">
    <property name="handlerMethod" ref="handlerMethod"   />
</bean>
```

Comment: Nope. I got the same error. Do I need to use MessageHandlerMethodFactory? Even though the above mentioned documentation does not say its mandatory; but there is a mention about it. I am not aware how to use it though.

Comment: As mentioned in the comment, the documentation is for `@JmsListener` NOT for the XML driven version.

Comment: @M.Deinum Okay. [This](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-namespace) is what I am trying to follow and I felt same effect as annotation could be achieved. Is there a way to achieve it using XML config?

Comment: No. It only accepts a message type (when using a marshaller) or a `Message` not both. You will have to use the annotation driven way if you want that.

Comment: i added a xml possibility, i have used this in past but not added a new argumentResolvers , this example is completed with PayloadArgumentResolver